# Deriving the relation between pressure, chemical potential and free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In reference [1], page 4173, the following relation is provided:
$$Z=P V /(N k T)=\mu /(k T)-A /(N k T)$$
where $Z$ is compressibility and $A$ is the Helmholtz free energy. This means pressure is:
$$P =\mu \frac{N}{V}-\frac{A}{V}$$
My question is, how can I derive this from definition of pressure which is $P=-\frac{\partial A}{\partial V}$ ?

[1] Gil-Villegas, Alejandro, et al. "Statistical associating fluid theory for chain molecules with attractive potentials of variable range." The Journal of chemical physics 106.10 (1997): 4168-4186.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better starting point is $A\equiv U-TS=-PV+\mu N$, the definition of the Helmholtz free energy. This can be immediately rearranged to provide

$$P=\frac{\mu N}{V}-\frac{A}{V},$$ QED.

In addition, from the [fundamental relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) $dU=T\,dS-P\,dV+\mu\,dN$, we have $dA=-S\,dT-P\,dV+\mu\,dN$, with $$P=-\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N}.$$

Make sense? Or are you specifically seeking a way to show the former starting from the latter?

Comment: To be more precise, your starting point is the definition of the Helmholtz free energy and the Euler equation resulting from being a homogeneous function of degree 1 of its extensive variables.

Comment: Right. We recognize that the first equation consists of [conjugate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_\(thermodynamics\)), each containing an intensive and an extensive variable. The energy scales up with the extensive variables, implying the fundamental relation (and also the [Gibbs–Duhem relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation), for consistency).

Comment: @Chemomechanics The first approach clarified it for me. Thanks